# Perform a LINQ query without using NotMapped properties in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following class:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And the following data:

- 1 / John / Doe
- 2 / Mike / Tyson
- 3 / John / Mc Enroe
- 4 / Stef / Doe

Now I need to let the user search for contacts like this:

- `John Doe` > get all contacts having the firstname `John` and the lastname `Doe`
- `John` > get all contacts having the first name `John`
- `Doe` > get all contacts having the last name `Doe`
- ...

I tried to add a `NotMapped` element to my class and perform my search on this (full) name but LINQ query does not work with `NotMapped` elements.

```
[NotMapped]
public string Name {
    get {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}

var someone = "John Doe";
requests.Where(s => s.Contact.Name.Contains(someone));
```

*The specified type member 'Name' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.*

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of computing the value in code, what about using a computed column in the database? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944904/how-should-i-access-a-computed-column-in-entity-framework-code-first has some info on that, if you read through everything.  You might be able to query on the computed column at that point (never tired so I don't know 100% for sure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to create a not mapped property to achieve what you need. You can try this:

```
var someone = "John Doe";
var contacts=context.Contacts.Where(c => String.Concat(c.FirstName, " ", p.LastName).Contains(someone));
```

The `String.Concact` method is supported by EF.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you.